# Displaying console output to TextArea in JavaFX FXML App

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I have a simple program along the lines of "Hello World" that uses `getText()` to retrieve the contents of two textFields and prints them out to console.  This works fine.

I have a TextArea defined I'd like to display the output to instead.  I have tried everything I have found but I'm getting all kinds of error's trying to adapt the answers to my code so please forgive me.

What I'd really appreciate is someone just to show me how and explain why your answer works please as I'm trying hard to learn.

Main Method:-

```
public class JavaFXApplication2 extends Application {



@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("gui.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}//end start method

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}//end main    
}//end class
```

And my controller

```
public class guiController implements Initializable {

//@FXML private Label label;
@FXML private TextField tf1;
@FXML private TextField tf2;
@FXML private TextArea ta; //want to display responses here


@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    System.out.println("IP Address " + tf1.getText() + " " + "Password: " + tf2.getText());

}//end event handler

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}//end init method    

}//end class
```

In simple terms I'd like the results of the `System.out.println("");` to appear in my text area called "ta".

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you just looking to replace the the `System.out.println(...)` with `ta.appendText(...)`?

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed..  I've added a `+ "\n" ` to the end so it uses a new line each time and it works great.  I wish you'd posted a proper answer so I could upvote so ty ty.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
ta.setText("IP Address " + tf1.getText() + " " + "Password: " + tf2.getText());
```

Comment: Yeah tried this but it only uses the same line each time setText is called but the answer above did the trick.  Thanks for your reponse.

Comment: ta.setWrapText(true);  and write ta.setText(ta.getText + ...);

Comment: That's still only using the same 1 line each time I click my button. James D's answer above is spot on as it uses a new line each click.